# "a lot tired" versus "very tired"

Tags: grammar, difference, adjectives

I have a question about words that describe feelings. Why is it you say "I am a little tired" or "I am very tired"? Why do you not say "I am a lot tired"?.

It seems to be this way for many adjectives that describe feelings: *a little sad, hungry, nervous, unhappy*. But it's always: *very sad, hungry, nervous, happy.*

Can you explain this to me please?
Thanks!

Comment: Okay, but what about "I ran a lot". Isn't "a lot" an adverb there? It could be replaced with "I ran quickly" or "I ran tirelessly". - I just read the answer below and it answered this for me.

Comment: Or "I get tired a lot."

Comment: @Giambattista I know, I was just adding on to Kelsey's comment.

Comment: So you can say, "I get tired a lot" with "a lot" as an adverb, but you cannot use "I am a lot tired"? How is it not an adverb in the second one if it is in the first? Is it an issue where "a lot" has a different part of speech depending on how it's used. As in: "a lot = often = adverb", but "a lot = a large amount = adjective"?

Comment: @Kelsey - The use of **a lot** is idiomatic in English. This means that it often doesn't follow any _rule_. Compounding the issue here, the verb **to get** (like **to be**) has many idiomatic usages as well. In any language, there are some words and usages that you just have to memorize, and I think the many uses of **a lot** (which you will often see as the single word **alot**) exemplify this.

Comment: @P.E.Dant is right. It's completely idiomatic; I just couldn't find a source other than [this](https://www.espressoenglish.net/common-errors-in-english-difference-between-so-very-and-a-lot/) to back it up. I deleted my answer because I couldn't properly source it. Well, at least I didn't spell it as [alot](https://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html)  :-)

Comment: You do sometimes see **"alot"** instead of **"a lot"**, but it's incorrect.  [There's a great cartoon about an imaginary creature called "the alot" that will help you remember!](http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html)

Answer (score 1):

> I'm a little sad.

This means you are sad, and the amount of that sadness is "little."

> I'm sad a lot.

This means you are often sad.  There's a lot of "events" where you are sad.

This is how you are supposed to use *a lot*.

> I get tired a lot.

This means you often get tired.

> I get a lot tired.

Technically, you can do this.  I think *tired* can be considered a "post-positive adjective" of *lot* - if we consider *lot* a noun.  Compare with "I wanted to buy a car painted" meaning you wanted to buy one that was already painted, or (from Wikipedia on "Postpositive adjectives") "every star visible is named after a famous astronomer".

*Get* is a [copular verb](http://www.englishgrammar.org/copular-verbs/) so that means it's "object" can be a "subject complement" - which means an adjective can follow.  So "I get tired" is fine, and I guess *a lot* could be considered an adverbial phrase that qualifies how (much) you get tired.  Usually adverbial phrases begin with a conjunction but there is at least one that begins with a determiner - *any time* - and I don't think *lest* is a conjunction in e.g. "lest she forget" ([reference](http://examples.yourdictionary.com/adverb-phrase-examples.html)).

But *lot* currently makes the most sense when it's used for countable things, e.g. *a lot of X*, even if they are implied in expressions like "I'm hungry a lot."

Answer (score 1):

I have seen/heard "a lot" used in the way you suggest, but only in a joking way.  "Are you a little tired?" "Oh, I'm a lot tired".  The two phrases do appear to be symmetrical, which is what makes the above a joke, because in fact they are not.  I don't have a good explanation, other than, as already said, it's idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

Like most "why" questions in language, the whole of the answer is "because that is the way it is". Sorry.

Comment: Prolixity be damned.

Answer (score 0):

I believe most native English speakers (I can only speak about US English here) would understand an ESL speaker saying "I am a lot tired" to be equivalent to "I am very tired" or "I am extremely tired" while "I am tired a lot" means "I am tired frequently" or "I am often tired". I suggest "I am a lot tired" is poor (ambiguous) English and should be avoided.

Comment: Welcome to ELL and thanks for your answer. If you provide examples to illustrate your point, it will make your answer more useful to subsequent visitors.